# Could I get some help installing google play store and services on my phone?

Tags: google-play-store, moto-x, motorola

I am using a Chinese issued  Morotola Moto X with Android version 5.1.1, some Chinese variation, I don't really have a name for. Either way, before when I installed the Google Store (with their help), it refused to run at all. Later I found out I needed to add the services app (Version 11.0.38) as well while updating the Google Play Store to 7.8.16, and now it at least starts, rather than immediately crashing. But now when it starts up, it takes me to the Checking info screen, before I get hit with a message that says "Unfortunately, Google Play Services has stopped."n Of course when I hit okay, it just shows the checking info screen endlessly. At the same time, I get a message that reads "Update Google Play Services as an alert message, but as far as I know, I am up to date. Clearly I have managed to make some progress, but I have never attempted something like this before. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Do to DRM I think there are now certifications that prevent it from being installled if it isn't already on stock android or if it's rooted.  You should be able to side load apps from other sites though.

Comment: Are you trying to install Google Play Services just to access the Play Store? Would you mind an intermediate solution which doesn't make use of the Play Services?

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the site [APKMirror.com](http://www.apkmirror.com/). On APKMirror, search for and download the latest version of the Google Play store 
The downloaded file will appear in the notifications pull-down menu at the top of your phone and in the Download folder in the app drawer. Click on the file in either location and install it. If you are unable to install the store, you may have to download the latest version of Google Play Services. You can [find a list here](http://www.apkmirror.com/page/2/?s=google+play+services), be sure to download the version that corresponds with the Android version you are running.

Be sure to have unknown sources enabled in the Security settings of your device.